# How to restart listening again after getting error 8 in speechrecognizer android?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have tried this code,but its not working,after getting error 8,its not listening again,what should i do?

```
@Override
public void listen() {
    myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sr.startListening(i); // here i is Intent,SpeechRecognizer sr;
        Log.d("message","start listening");
    }
});
```

}

```
@Override
public void onError(int error) {
    Log.d("message","error occurred! "+error);
    if(error==8) {
        sr.destroy();
        myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
          public void run() {
            sr.startListening(i);
            Log.d("message","again start listening");
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error ERROR\_RECOGNIZER\_BUSY with offline speech recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866239/error-error-recognizer-busy-with-offline-speech-recognition)

Comment: Just avoid using speech recognizer twice, there will be no such error.